# (Native Module) Android Bluetooth return error: read failed , socket might closed or timeout, read ret -1

Tags: android, bluetooth, native-module

I tried to connect using `BluetoothSocket` but get error **read failed , socket might closed or timeout, read ret -1**, am i missing something?

below is the code i use to test it in native module:

```
@ReactMethod
public void connectToDevice(String address, Callback callback) {
        
    BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if (device == null) {
        callback.invoke("Device not found");
        return;
    }
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    try {
        BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        socket.connect();
        callback.invoke(null, "Connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        callback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

in the react native:

```
const renderDevice = ({ item }: { item: Device }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
      BluetoothScannerModule.connectToDevice(item.address, (error: string | null, message: string) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log(message);
        }
      });
    }}>
      <Text>{item.name ?? 'Unnamed device'}</Text>
      <Text>{item.address}</Text>
      <Text>Bond state: {item.bondState}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

<Modal visible={isModalVisible} transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}>
   <View style={styles.modal}>
      <FlatList data={devices} renderItem={renderDevice} />
      <Button title='Close' onPress={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}/>
   </View>
</Modal>
```

and I'm new to this, so is it possible without doing any pairing before using `BluetoothSocket`?

Comment: try adding a finally block with: if(socket != null) socket.close();

Comment: i'll try it first and see if it can works, thank you for the suggestion